# Output Post-Order Binary Search Tree from Given Pre-Order input without constructing tree or using recursions

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, preorder, postorder

Problem Description: (language is java)

Given an input array representing a preorder traversal of a binary search tree, output a postorder traversal of the BST.

**Catch :**

- No construction of BST nodes.
- No recursions.
- O(n) running time.

I have tried figuring it out for hours, but still have no clues.
The hardest part is without using the tree node struct.
Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

here is a hint :

In `preorder` traversal, the first element of the array is always going to be the *root* of the tree, 
so if, `NodeElemnts[]` is given array, then `NodeElemnts[0]` *will be* the root of the trees

then, left node is located at `2n+1` and right node is located at `2n+2`, `n` being the index of current array.

for Pre to Post :

`[root][leftChild][rightChild]` (*pre*) -> `[leftChild][rightChild][root]` (*post*) .....think BFS :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The problem is that BST is not full tree and a node could have or not have a left/right child.

Comment: in that case, you wont have method to find out which tree node has which tree child...assumption would be that tree is full tree!! :)

Comment: a BST is very rarely a full tree unless it is a AVL tree or Red-Black tree. It is possible to find the children since the left child is n + 1 if the tree has a left child and the right child is the first number larger than the node.